# Js check if date string is valid but returns valid even for incorrect dates

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

im checking if the string is a valid date or not and this is my if statement

```
if ((new Date(str).toString()) !== 'Invalid Date') {
        return moment.utc(str).local().format('DD/MM/YYYY')
   }
```

but when it gets the following inputs it accepts these as a date

DEV-50003 
NATSD-10002 
NATSD-10003 
NATSD-10004

what's the problem here?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Date parses all four values into a date, e.g., DEV-50003 = Wed Jan 01 50003.  For details about how it works see: [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#examples)

Comment: btw you can use moment strict mode if you know the input format. not sure if it is possible without input format

Comment: This has nothing to do with React or Vue.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson why? are they using PHP, not JS? :D

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison !== is comparing data types as well and that new Date(str).toString()) when given an invalid date returns a literal string while you are comparing it to a string. Easy fix here is to change the comparison to != or put double quotes ie: "Invalid Date" rather than 'Invalid Date'

Answer (score 0):

after a while, I found a solution.

I removed Date and used moment and its strict mode.

```
if (moment(str, moment.ISO_8601).isValid()) {
        return moment.utc(str).local().format('DD/MM/YYYY')
   }
```

this worked for me. hope this one will help someone else 
Thanks.